# Java cipher game

Tags: java

I'm creating a cipher game and Im so stuck. So I have an array list of 6 sentences and a char array of the alphabet. The program should print out encrypted version of the sentences but each time a different letter is assigned to the original letters. For example the word "Hello" would become "Ipiiu" ( h < I , p<e , l<i, o<u).

I have no idea how to do this. The code below replaces the letters permanently but I want each time the user plays the letters to be different. How do I do this?

```
   public static void replaceString(ArrayList<String> arr, char[] alphabet) {
    
    Random r = new Random();
    
    String s1 = arr.get(0);
    
    String sentence1 = s1.toLowerCase()
            .replace("a", "t")
            .replace("r", "m")
            .replace("t", "p")
            .replace("n", "h")
            .replace("s", "u")
            .replace("f", "b")
            .replace("u", "n")
            .replace("w", "l")
            .replace("v", "a")
            .replace("y", "r")
            .replace("o", "j")
            .replace("h", "d");
    
            
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to write the code, but I'll give you a tip:  Make a `Map<char, char>` and use that to convert your words ;)

Comment: p.s.  If you want to go into hard mode, you could write quite complex rules in Regex Expression, and use those to alter your words.  #hardmode

Comment: `.relpace()` returns a String object which serves as input for the next `replace()` command. That means "no".replace("n", "h").replace("h", "d") will replace all the 'n' with 'h' and then **in the resulting String 'ho'** replace all 'h' with 'd'.

Comment: What is the use of the `alphabet` array?

Comment: @AKSingh every time the user plays new letters of the alphabet should be used, so if a was assigned to 'x' , next time the user plays 'a' cant be assigned to 'x' again

Comment: Your existing code won’t work as mentioned above. You can’t use `replace()` to do this. You need to do something like iterating through the characters and filling a StringBuilder. Use a Map to represent the cipher if it’s a simple letter substitution like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is basically something called a substitution cipher.

To make this work, you need to do first create a substitution table that maps a character to another (E.g. h to l, p to e etcetera)

After which, encrypting and decrypting is as simple as a lookup to the substitution table.

I did a short attempt at this and the code is as follow:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CipherTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i='a'; i<='z'; i++)
            characters.add((char)i);
        Collections.shuffle(characters);
        
        //Generate Substitution Table
        Map<Character, Character> substitutionTable = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        int listIndex = 0;
        for(int i='a'; i<='z'; i++)
            substitutionTable.put((char)i,characters.get(listIndex++));
        substitutionTable.put(' ' , ' ');
        
        //Print Substitution table
        System.out.println("Substitution Table:");
        substitutionTable.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue() + " ; ");  
         });
        System.out.println();
        
        //Encrypt
        String plaintext = "hello world";
        String encrypted = encrypt(substitutionTable,plaintext);
        System.out.println("Encrypted " + plaintext + " to " + encrypted);
        
        
        //Decrypt
        String decrypted = decrypt(substitutionTable, encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted " + encrypted + " to " + decrypted);
   }
    
    public static String encrypt(Map<Character,Character> substitutionTable, String plaintext){
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char character : plaintext.toCharArray())
            sb.append(substitutionTable.get(character));
        String encrypted = sb.toString();
       return encrypted;
    }
    
    public static String decrypt(Map<Character,Character> substitutionTable, String encrypted){
        Map<Character,Character> substitutionTableInversed = substitutionTable.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        for(char character : encrypted.toCharArray())
            sb2.append(substitutionTableInversed.get(character));
        String decrypted = sb2.toString();
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

The output of the above code will look something like this:

```
Substitution Table:
 :  ; a:d ; b:r ; c:u ; d:g ; e:s ; f:f ; g:c ; h:b ; i:y ; j:q ; k:x ; l:p ; m:k ; n:z ; o:i ; p:e ; q:v ; r:a ; s:l ; t:n ; u:m ; v:h ; w:w ; x:o ; y:t ; z:j ;
Encrypted hello world to bsppi wiapg
Decrypted bsppi wiapg to hello world
```

On each run of the game, the output will change as you wanted because the lookup table is dynamically generated on each run

Comment: is there a way to do this with just using array lists?

Comment: I keep getting "null" text in between the sentences

Comment: For the null: see my edited answer. Basically you need to have the mapping for ' ' --> ' '. Space must map to space.

Comment: You can use arraylist for sure but you probably shouldn't. This will be done by storing a tuple in each list item. <character, character> as well. In searching the table, you need to repeatedly iterate the list. In inserting, you get no assurance for duplicates. So yes you can but you probably should not

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem is based on the method to encrypt a text with exchange table. Since the objective is to obtain a different letter exchange each time, the correct way to do it is by using a different exchange table each time.

You have to create a different key for each cipher otherwise your code won't work as you want.